# Action on selected layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I have a bunch of Smart Objects in a .psd. I want to create an action that opens up the .psb of each individual Smart Object and scale the .psb image size by 150%.

The reason for all this is that each .psb contains a Vector Smart Object, and if I scale the Smart Object from the parent .psd the result is a blurry mess. So the only solution as I see it, is to open up each .psb and scale the image size by 150%.

I don't know if it's possible to do this with a Photoshop Action, so that photoshop performs the above hokus-pokus on the *selected* layer? I can only get an action to work on a *specific* layer?

Alternatively it might be possible to do this with a jsx-script, any hints on how to go about this is also highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you need scripting. Actions won't do this. But I can't really help with scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created an action that can do this. You can download it here:

[Scale up PSB](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81328/Scale%20up%20PSB.atn)

And that is how you use it:

1. Do a layer filtering for Smart Objects
2. Select the first layer
3. Run the action
4. Repeat running the action until you reach the last Smart Object

The action opens up the Smart Object, scales it up to 150%, saves the PSB, and selects the next layer. I have tried to insert a loop, but that does not seem to be possible.

I created the action in a german version of PS CS6, I hope that does not matter.